# A Seemingly Trivial but Computationally Complicated Probability Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

> Suppose $X,Y$ are independent $Uniform(-1,1)$ random variables. Determine the distribution of $Z=X-Y$.

I do not really think I should add my work here because whatever I have tried until now, has turned out to be extremely complicated in terms of inequalities. The main difficulty of this problem I would say, lies in carving out the appropriate regions in which certain probabilities are non-zero. But anyway, I am sketching out my method which is apparently a failure.

> $P(X-Y<t)=\int_{y}P(X<t+y)f_Y(y)dy$
>
> It is to be observed that if $t+y<-1$ then $P(X<t+y)=0$. So we need $t+y>-1$ i.e. $y>-1-t$. But $y>-1$ (otherwise $f_Y(y)=0$ ) so $y>\max\{-1,-1-t\}$. So we have got the lower bound for $y$.
>
> If $t+y>1$ i.e. if $y>1-t$ then $P(X<t+y)=1$ so for this case, $y>\max\{-1,-1-t,1-t\}$. But, $-1-t<1-t$ hence we need just $y>\max\{-1,1-t\}$.

After this point, I gave up. There are too many inequalities and things happening. It is just too hard to keep track of which region I am working with.

Is there a better method? If yes, I would appreciate it. If not, please comment and I have to proceed with this tiresome logic.

Comment: Have you ever done the sum of two independent uniforms on $[0,1]$? Are you comfortable with the geometric approach there?

Comment: I have solved the problem on sum of two independent uniforms on $[0,1]$ but I did that too algebraically, with these methods. I am sorry I do not know about any geometric approach.

Comment: By symmetry this is the same as the distribution of $X+Y$. If you have done the sum of two independent uniforms on $(0,1)$, the density function of $Z$ will have the same basic shape, just shifted and scaled.

Comment: So are you suggesting that I transform these random variables into uniform variables on $[0,1]$ and then re-try the problem? That seems a nice idea!! But wait. Let me clarify the necessary transformations then. If the new variables be $X'$ and $Y'$ then we must be looking for $\dfrac{X'-0}{1-0}=\dfrac{X+1}{2}$ and similarly $\dfrac{Y'-0}{1-0}=\dfrac{Y+1}{2}$. How will $t$ change in this case? Should it be $t'=\dfrac{t}{2}+1$?

Comment: It is not really a nice idea, you can do things directly as Alex R. suggests. Just mentioned it since you had done it on $(0,1)$. It would be let $U=(X+1)/2$, $V=(Y+1)/2$. You know the density function of $U+V$. Now $X+Y=2(U+V)-2$. But you can set up the integral, or better compute area, without transforming to a more familiar problem.

Answer (score 3):

1) Draw the square $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$. in the cartesian plane. The value of $X$ is on the $x$ axis, $Y$ on the $Y$ axis.

2) Asking the probability of $Z\leq s$ is equivalent to finding the area under the the line $x-y=s$, bounded by the square.

3) Find this area using simple geometry.

Comment: You lost a minus sign in the interval in $Y$, but a good approach.

Comment: The values are between $-2$ and $2$. The density function of $Z$ is *symmetric* about the origin. So we need only find it for positive $z$.

Comment: So, for probabilities like this, it is more prudent to proceed according to areas, correct? But suppose I added an extra condition, say, $P(X-Y<t|Y>t/2)$. Then, is a geometric interpretation possible? Or is there, then, an algebraic approach more favorable?